# HashiCorp Terraform / HCL language support doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, terraform

I've installed the `HashiCorp Terraform / HCL language support` to support terraform coding, but its just the same with it.

[image: syntax highlight doesn't work]

Making sure the plugin is enabled:

[image]

What i've configured wrong?
I got IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2018.3.2

Answer (score 5):

There was a need to set `*.tf` as a registered pattern for the `Terraform config` in the `Preferences->Editor->File Types`, previously it was assigned to `Text`

[image]